# Secure Upload (SSL) a file in to Amazon S3 in c#

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ssl, amazon-s3

Currently I am working on a MVC application, I want to upload a file(s) to amazon s3 using SSL from c#. (Sometimes i need to upload using SSL and some other times without SSL based on boolean value).

Thanks in Advance..

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: My scenario is, I need to upload a file either using http or https.. These http and https should change based on end user selection (based on End user selection). Is this possible to change http to https only when end user selected a Checkbox before performing Click action.

Answer (score 0):

All S3 endpoints support both HTTP and HTTPS so it shouldn't be a problem to use either one, based on your use case.

You can see the full list of endpoints on:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#s3_region